# I want to extract Map from List<Map<String, Employee>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've written the code below:

```java
Map<String,Employee> empObj = empListObject.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

But it gives me a compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,Employee>
```

Comment: What's emptyListObject like?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution without using `flatMap`.  It uses `mapMulti`.  Also, you didn't say whether the the  maps had  duplicate keys either among the different maps.  If that is true then you need to consider that and save the duplicate keys to a list of `Employee`.  In lieu of a class I am using a `record` for the `Employee` for demo but it will work the same as a class.

**Data**

```
    
record Employee(String name) {
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

List<Map<String, Employee>> mapList = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(Map.of("A", new Employee("John")),
                Map.of("B", new Employee("Mary"), "C", new Employee("Sara")),
                Map.of("A", new Employee("Bob")),
                Map.of("C", new Employee("John"), "D",new Employee("Joan"))));
```

**Method**

- Stream the maps as you were doing
- then place each `Entry<String,Employee>` on the stream.
- then collect into a map of `Map<String, List<Employee>>`

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> map = mapList.stream()
    .<Entry<String, Employee>>mapMulti((m, consumer) -> m
                        .entrySet().forEach(consumer))  
                ).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
                
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**prints**

```
A=[John, Bob]
B=[Mary]
C=[Sara, John]
D=[Joan]
```

**Notes:**

- `mapMulti` needs a type witness to tell it the stream is changing types.  Hence the preceding `<Entry<String, Employee>>`
- if there are no duplicate keys between all the maps, the the simple `toMap` collector is fine.
- whether you use `flatMap` or `mapMulti`, you still need to handle duplicates if they exist.